# Is there any Graph QL explorer?

Tags: api, graphql

I need to send GraphQL queries to some site which is not in my control. Is there any way I could send those queries using explorer like https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/explorer ?

Answer (score 5):

What GitHub calls "Explorer" is actually just Facebook's open source GraphQL console called [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) (pronounced "graphical"). Someone built a standalone version with electron [here](https://github.com/skevy/graphiql-app).

Comment: Please note the `graphql playground` project https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground that is based on `GraphiQL`